# ExtJS6: How to add a close icon on tabpanel items

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have a tabpanel as main container and attaching panels to it it as items dynamically when clicked. But my tabs only have title assigned to child items. How do I add a close button next to title and close tab when being clicked

Comment: Use the `closable` config on each item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put one config `closabe : true` in your item whichever you want to close.

Here is example code.

```
Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();
Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
width: 400,
height: 400,
renderTo: document.body,
items: [{
    title: 'Foo',
    closable : true
}, {
    title: 'Bar',
    closable : true,
    tabConfig: {
        title: 'Custom Title',
        tooltip: 'A button tooltip'
    }
}]
});
```